# SQL Comparing values by date range in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables in Sql Server 2008 -> SchedulePermanent and ScheduleImported

SchedulePermanent:

> **Id StartDate EndDate Value**
>
> 1 01-01-2013 03-01-2013 100
>
> 2 03-01-2013 07-01-2013 200
>
> 3 07-01-2013 18-01-2013 300

CheduleImported:

> **Id StartDate EndDate Value**
>
> 1 01-01-2013 04-01-2013 100
>
> 2 04-01-2013 06-01-2013 200
>
> 3 06-01-2013 15-01-2013 300
>
> 4 15-01-2013 18-01-2013 100

I want to insert into a result table only values that are not equal in the two schedules for each day.

Examlple: (OldValue: present in the permanent table, NewValue present in the import table)

> **Date OldValue NewValue**
>
> 03-01-2013 200 100
>
> 06-01-2013 200 300
>
> 15-01-2013 300 100
>
> 16-01-2013 300 100
>
> 17-01-2013 300 100
>
> 18-01-2013 300 100

Do i have to split each table in temporary tables by date and then do the comparison for each date or is there a better way? (I saw some topics talking about Cross join but i have never used it)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a cross join, you should be able to do this with just an inner join.

```
select Date, SchedulePermanent.Value as OldValue, ScheduleImported.AsNewValue
from SchedulePermanent 
join ScheduleImported on SchedulePermanent.StartDate = ScheduleImported.StartDate and SchedulePermanent.Value <> ScheduleImported.Value
```

However, that will only work to import values for dates that already exist in SchedulePermanent. To include values from imported that don't yet exist in permanent, it would look something like this:

```
    select Date, SchedulePermanent.Value as OldValue, ScheduleImported.AsNewValue
    from SchedulePermanent 
    right join ScheduleImported on SchedulePermanent.StartDate = ScheduleImported.StartDate 
where SchedulePermanent.StartDate is null
```

If you want to overwrite the values, then you could check out a merge statement, instead.

```
 MERGE SchedulePermanent AS target
    USING (SELECT StartDate, Value from ScheduleImported) AS source 
    ON (target.StartDate = source.StartDate)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Value = source.Value
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (StartDate, Value)
        VALUES (source.StartDate, source.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but it does not resolve my problem for the moment. The Start dates in the tables usualy are not the same and the endDates also. I need a trace of a day by day difference ( it there is a difference in the values)

Comment: If the start dates aren't usually the same, then wouldn't you want to insert the new value as a completely new record, and not overwrite some old value? That's what my MERGE example shows

Answer (score 0):

a simple way for you to get all the unequal records:

```
SELECT S.ID, S.StartDate, S.Value
FROM SchedulePermanent AS S
WHERE S.Value NOT EXSIST(
     SELECT VALUE
     FROM CheduleImported AS C
     WHERE C.StartDate = S.StartDate AND C.EndDate = S.EndDate
)
```

Comment: beyond that, you can insert into the table where this records only in this set

Comment: The Start dates in the tables usualy are not the same and the endDates also